# Nested for-loop and variable naming

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to name my variables in the following manner:

```
for (( a=1; a<=10; a++ )); do
    for (( b=1; b<=100; b++ )); do
        line[$a]position[$b]="This is LINE $a at POSITION $b."
        eval echo "${line[a]position[b]}"
    done
done
```

Is this possible and my code is just wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible the way you try it. First of all, `[]` are not allowed in names (see [definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions) in the manual), so you'd have to use a name like `line${a}position$b`.

One ([mostly frowned upon](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) option is to use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( a=1; a<=2; a++ )); do
    for (( b=1; b<=2; b++ )); do
        varname=line${a}position$b
        eval $varname=\"This is LINE \$a at POSITION \$b.\"
        echo "${!varname}"
    done
done
```

This first creates the string to be used as the variable name, `varname`. It becomes, for each loop, `line1position1`, `line1position2` and so on.

Then, on this line, we assign your string to the variable with that name:

```
eval $varname=\"This is LINE \$a at POSITION \$b.\"
```

The quoting is such that the string expands to, for example for the first loop,

```
line1position1="This is LINE $a at POSITION $b."
```

and the value of `line1position1` becomes `This is LINE 1 at POSITION 1.`.

To access the value of this variable, we have to use [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): the `!` in `${!varname}` indicates that `varname` is not the variable name we want, but *expands* to it.

This all being said, Bash 4.3 introduced [*namerefs*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters), which allow to solve this much more elegantly:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( a=1; a<=2; a++ )); do
    for (( b=1; b<=2; b++ )); do
        declare -n refvar=line${a}position$b
        refvar="This is LINE $a at POSITION $b."
        echo "$refvar"
    done
done
```

No `eval` required here.

The output for both solutions is this:

```
This is LINE 1 at POSITION 1.
This is LINE 1 at POSITION 2.
This is LINE 2 at POSITION 1.
This is LINE 2 at POSITION 2.
```